# ordering of Hashtable in J2ME

Tags: java-me, hashtable

I have some data and I have added them to Hashtable in some orders what I want to do now is to get the data in the same order that I have entered

What is the data type that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your key is a String you could add some ordering to it and have a getter method for the sorted data. See example below:

```
    static int order;
    Hashtable map = new Hashtable();

    void put (String key, Object value) {
        map.put(order + key, value);
        order++;
    }

    Enumeration getSorted() {
        Enumeration keys = map.keys();
        Vector sortedKeys = new Vector();

        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
            insertionSort(key, sortedKeys);
        }

        Vector sortedData = new Vector();
        keys = sortedKeys.elements();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
            sortedData.addElement(map.get(key));
        }

        return sortedData.elements();
    }
```

You can find insertionSort algorithms at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Answer (score 2):

A `Hashtable` does not retain any ordering.
If you need insertion order access see if [Linked Hash Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) is offered in `JavaME`

Comment: The LinkedHashMap is not exist in J2ME, How can I do that without LinkedHashMap???

Comment: Do you need `O(1)` search time?

Answer (score 0):

You can download a source code of Java SE and make work LinkedHashMap in J2ME easily by removing generics (but also you might need to perform this on it's parent classes and interfaces).
You can find LinkedHashMap for Java ME [here](http://docd.zx6.ru/proj/j2me/Port/port.zip)